# How to check for the value of a constant for conditional compilation?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a constant `#define`'ed as such:

```
#define FRUIT APPLE
```

I would like at a later point conditionally compile code based on what `FRUIT` has been `#define`'ed as.

I tried the following, but it seems to always evaluate to true.

```
#if (FRUIT == APPLE)
  printf("The fruit is an apple!\n");
#endif
```

Comment: What is `APPLE` defined as in the above code? What else could `FRUIT` be defined as? If they're macros that exist but haven't been given a value they default to 0 IIRC so it looks like you're saying `#if (0 == 0)`

Comment: You need something like `#define APPLE 1` and `#define ORANGE 2`.

Comment: Instead of defining variables like this, you could use `#define FRUIT_APPLE`, `#define FRUIT_ORANGE`, etc. Then you can use `#ifdef FRUIT_APPLE`

Comment: Apart from `cout` indicating this is a C++ question, this _crafting_ of the executable may be better served by using the compile command line's facility of `-DBANANA` instead of a `#define` that necessitates editing the code repeatedly. Each variety of the executable could then be put into an appropriately named executable.

Comment: @Fe2O3 You're completely right about the `cout` part, I changed accordingly. Unfortunately, this question (obviously) is a simplification of a large project, and it seems that the only fix would be for me to manually add `#define IS_APPLE` at many different places, and just use a `#ifdef IS_APPLE` at the print statement part.

Comment: @Fahrradkettem "I tried the following, " --> post a [mcve] to clearly show what you have done.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for informing me, will read.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add another `#define` and use it as such:

```
#define FRUIT APPLE
#define IS_APPLE

#ifdef IS_APPLE
  printf("The fruit is an apple!\n");
#endif
```

Comment: This does not meet the question's goal: "check for the _value_ of a constant" nor does it relate to the other macro.   This answer only checks the existence of a macro, not its _value_.  IIRC an undefine macro has a value of 0.

Comment: You are right. But it seems to me from the comments to the main question that the answer seems to be "there is no way to do this the way you want, you'd have to try this work around ...".

Comment: Still hoping for a [mcve].

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I read the document. It seems to me my example is already minimal. What else is needed? a `main()` function for completeness?

Comment: They context that is missing is how `FRUIT APPLE` and `IS_APPLE` are used in various situations. With only 1 example, this answer reduces to `printf("The fruit is an apple!\n");` with no `#defines` at all. So it seems we need a _less_ minimal example.

Comment: Are we talking about the main question or the proposed answer here?

Comment: Both lack an alternate case as they show "here is what I want in one case" yet no other cases presented.